# Echo XML contents in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have an image generated with PHP that contains dynamically generated text. The data it was originally sourcing from has changed to a different format, from JSON to XML. I'm unfamiliar with XML and related PHP commands.

What I wish to do is to echo a specific part of the XML page/file. For example, if the data is structured in this manner:

```
<sometag>
    <anothertag>
        <tag1>ABC123</tag1>
        <tag2>DEF456</tag2>
        <tag3>GHI789</tag3>
    </anothertag>
</sometag>
```

If I want to echo the contents of, say, tag2, what would I need to do? Is there some sort of $xml->tag2 feature, similar to how it works with JSON?

Comment: You can use simpleXML to get the values.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php for simpleXML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/simplexml.examples-basic.php) library.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_string);
echo $xml->anothertag->tag2;
//DEF456
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks.